# Rails: SQL SELECT Statement Not Appearing When Combined With GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in Ruby:

```
Comment.select("comments.*, COALESCE(SUM(votes.value), 0) AS rating,
  user_votes.value AS user_value").
  joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.voteable_type = '"+type+"' AND votes.voteable_id = comments.id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN votes AS user_votes ON user_votes.voteable_type = '"+type+"' AND user_votes.voteable_id = comments.id AND user_votes.user_id = #{user_id}").
  where(conditions).group("comments.id").order("comments."+method).limit(limit).offset(offset)
```

When Rails generates this SQL query, it doesn't include the full select statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, comments.id AS comments_id FROM `comments`
LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.voteable_type = 'reply' AND votes.voteable_id = comments.id 
LEFT JOIN votes AS user_votes ON user_votes.voteable_type = 'reply' AND 
user_votes.voteable_id = comments.id AND user_votes.user_id = 1 WHERE (commentable_id = 
1 AND commentable_type = 'Impression')
GROUP BY comments.id ORDER BY comments.rating DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

If I remove the group statement, however, then it properly includes the full select statement. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select comments.* in your select statement conflicts with  group by("comments.id").

Every column selected must either be in the GROUP BY clause or be contained in an aggregate function.

SQL Server shows error for SQL: 
  select c.* from tt_country c group by c.name

Column 'tt_country.country_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

ActiveRecord and arel throws out the specified select because it is ambiguous / invalid.